# Relationship between integral and differential equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show that (1) implies (2):

(1) y'' + y = sin 2x,  $y(0)=1 $ and $y'(0)=0$

(2) y(x)= $1$ + $\frac{1}{2}$x - $\frac{1}{4}$sin 2x - $\int_0^x  (x-t)y(t)dt$

What I did:

y''= sin 2x - y

y'= $-\frac{1}{2}$cos 2x - $\int_0^x y'(t)dt $ + $y'(0)$

y'= $-\frac{1}{2}$cos 2x- $\int_0^x [\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}cos 2t - \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t ((t-a)y(a) da)] dt$

I am not sure how to continue from there, I know it's using fundamental theorem of calculus, I tried different possibilities and just left the $ (t-a)y(a) $ term as it is, but somehow I still have an extra $\frac{1}{4} sin 2x$ at the end.

Was I right up to this point? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found out that by the fundamental theorem applied twice you get
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(s)ds=f(0)+f'(0)x+\int_0^x(x-s)f''(s)ds
$$
Now set $f(x)=y(x)+\frac14\sin(2x)$ so that $f''(x)=y''(x)-\sin(2x)=-y(x)$ to get
$$
y(x)+\frac14\sin(2x)=1+\frac x2 - \int_0^x(x-s)y(s)ds.
$$

Comment: Why did you multiply $f'(0)$ with $x$ in the first line, and how did $\int_0^xf'(s)ds$ become $\int_0^x(x-s)f''(s)ds$ ?

Comment: This is partial integration based on $\dfrac{d}{ds}((x-s)f'(s))=-f'(s)+(x-s)f''(s)$. This is one of the proof principles you can find for the Taylor expansion. Or you could directly look that up with the integral remainder term.